# What happens when there are no submissions for PotW contest?

Tags: discussion, contest, rules

After 8 days into the 2-week photo contest, [Photo Competition 2021-07-19: Inspired by Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125387/photo-competition-2021-07-19-inspired-by-photography-stack-exchange), there haven't been any submissions. This is a first for the New (2021) PotW contests.

2 comments to the competition question:

> 1. Seriously, this is the least inspiring theme yet.
> 2. Maybe we could switch to the next theme?

What should be the protocol if the PotW theme doesn't produce any submissions? Should the mods just switch to the next upcoming/proposed theme? Perhaps switch to a open submission "non theme" contest for the remaining fractional week (or 1 1/2 weeks for biweekly contests)?

Comment: For 2021, the PotW contests have been running for 2 weeks, and the top 2 submissions have been posted for a week each after each contest. However, the previous contest produced a tie for 2nd/3rd place, so in fairness, that contest should show 3 consecutive PotW sidebar features. So **in this particular instance**, I need another week to run the other 2nd place tie PotW.

Comment: We've had second place ties a couple of times, might not be a bad idea to define how we deal with that situation.

Comment: @LightBender I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure the first time we had a 2nd place tie was for Street Photography. I think there was an instance a couple months ago where the _net votes_ were tied for 2nd, but one of them had a downvote, and additional upvote to cancel the DV. I always check, and pick, most **upvotes**.

Comment: Long Exposure and Deep Thought both had a no down votes tie.

Comment: @LightBender Oh yikes. I'm going back and looking. I must not have sorted by votes on Long Exposure, because I featured the _10th place_ photo instead of either of the 2nd place ties. Wow, I screwed that one up. ‍

Answer (score 1):

At least in this case, I think you should delete the photo competition question and start the next competition (which would run for slightly less than 2 weeks). This would also allow you run the other 2nd place image on the sidebar for a week.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just let this one run its course and hope for a better theme next time. I really can't believe this theme was the top of anyones list however. I really think themes should be broad and general. If you start getting too many entries then we can deal with that problem.